# Trouble when user tries to re-submit after initial submit had errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

Here's my current user flow:

1. **Enter email on home page** ==> If email is valid, new Signup record is created, and user is redirected to step 2; if email is not valid, new Signup record is not created and home page is re-rendered for user to resubmit email
2. **Enter rest of signup information** (let's just say zipcode) on edit signup page ==> If the zipcode is valid, the Signup record is updated and the user progresses to the rest of the website, else, this edit signup page is re-rendered with errors for the user to resubmit zipcode

There are two separate validations for the same signup, once on the home page to make sure the email is valid, once on the edit page on the update action to ensure the zipcode is valid.

(Why this troublesome two-step? Users might be too intimidated to enter in their information at step 2, but I at least want to capture their interest via their email on my mailing list to reach out in the future.)

I'm running into very annoying problems, represented by these flows:

*Example 1*

1. Enter invalid email on home page ==> No Signup record is created, home page is re-rendered with errors
2. Enter valid email on re-rendered home page ==> New Signup record is now saved (I checked in console), BUT instead of allowing user to progress to the edit signup page, the home page re-renders with the error messages saying that zipcode is invalid.
3. If user somehow has patience to click submit again without changing the email... then they're redirected correctly to the edit signup page... but understandably users get frustrated before this point and don't click again

*Example 2*

1. Enter valid but bizarre email on home page (e.g., t@bizafre.com) ==> New Signup record is now saved, BUT again instead of allowing user to progress to the edit signup page, the home page re-renders with the error messages saying that zipcode is invalid
2. Again as above, if user has patience to click submit again without changing the email... then they'r redirected correctly

It seems that the zipcode validation is somehow triggering in the creation step, but I really don't understand why... I have a theory in a comment on the controller code regarding parameters, but a theory that I don't have the answer for either.

Help appreciated!

**Model code**

```
class Signup

  validate :create_validation, on: :create
  validate :update_validation, on: :update

  def create_validation
    errors[:base] << "Please enter a valid email address to continue" if self.email.blank? || (( /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i =~ self.email) == nil) 
  end

  def update_validation
    errors[:base] << "Please enter a valid 5-digit zipcode so we can find items closer to you" if self.zipcode.blank? || (self.zipcode < 0) || (self.zipcode.to_s.strip.length != 5)
  end

end
```

**Routes code**

```
root 'signups#new' #normal code
resources :signups, only: [:new, :create]
get '/edit', to: 'signups#edit', as: 'edit_signup'
patch 'signups/update', to: 'signups#update'
```

**Controller code**

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

  def create
    @signup = Signup.new
    email = signup_params["email"] 

    if Signup.where(email: email.downcase).exists?
        session[:signup_email] = email.downcase
        redirect_to action: 'edit'
    else
        @signup = Signup.create(signup_params) 
        # I wonder if signup_params the problem since it also has zipcode? If so how do I change it? I tried writing Signup.create(email), or Signup.create(signup_params["email"]) or Signup.create(signup_params[:email]) and kept getting the error: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

        if @signup.save
            Subscribe.new.async.perform(@signup)
            Mailing.new.async.perform(@signup)
            session[:signup_email] = @signup.email
            redirect_to action: 'edit'
        else
            render new_signup_path
        end
    end

  end

  def edit
    if session[:signup_email].nil?
      flash[:danger] = "Please enter your email to get started"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @signup_parent = Signup.find_by_email(session[:signup_email])
    end
  end

  def update
    @signup_parent = Signup.find_by_email(session[:signup_email])
    if @signup_parent.update_attributes(signup_params)
        redirect_to success_path
    else
        render "edit"
    end 
  end

  def signup_params 
     params.require(:signup).permit(:email, :zipcode) 
  end

end
```

Comment: looking at your code, it seems like you didn't just copy paste the model since you're missing the `< ActiveRecord::Base` line so there may be an issue that isn't visible, but otherwise, i think this is a weird behavior.  try using different params for create and update.  create a method called `create_signup_params` and only allow the `email`. then another called `update_signup_params` and only allow the `zipcode`

Comment: Yeah sorry it's inheriting from AR::Base properly. I tried the different params set up... didn't solve the problem

Comment: that's actually good news.  At least it's consistent.  try changing the validations to the normal `validates :email, presence: true, on: :create` and `validates :zipcode, presence: true, on: :update` just to test things out.

Comment: same behavior with normal `validates` statements. what are you thinking?

Comment: i just want to eliminate other scenarios.  it's good that it behaves the same.  unfortunately, i don't have any other idea.  when you test again, just make sure that you have a clean db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy crap I fixed the problem! In the Signups controller, these two lines were messing it up

```
@signup = Signup.create(signup_params) 
if @signup.save
...
```

`create` already includes `save` so when the second `save` is called, THAT's why the update validation kicks in. New code:

```
@signup = Signup.new(signup_params) 
if @signup.save
...
```

Two interesting points I'd still love comments on:

1. I'm not sure why clicking submit again fixed the problem in the old version and led to the `/edit` page, since the problem with validation should have kicked in again
2. I'm curious why the line `if @signup.create(signup_params)` didn't work since that's syntactically the same as the `new` + the `save`. What happens there is that if the user enters a string that's not a valid email, e.g., "asfd", the `edit` page is triggered even though no `Signup` record has been recorded (meaning that an error occurs since `@signup_parent` doesn't exist)